# Grep entire list of dicts in Python and get the last match

Tags: python-3.x

By running a command, I get a list like below:

```
>>> 
>>> list=[{'project': 'myproject', 'branch': 'master', 'id': 'I39d41e926a436777e4839e616a6c78885d9bbcd3', 'number': '62630', 'owner': {'name': 'reodee', 'email': 'reodee@mymail.com', 'username': 'reodee'}, 'comments': [{'timestamp': 1536964726, 'reviewer': {'name': 'Sam', 'email': 'sams@mymail.com', 'username': 'sams'}, 'message': 'Uploaded patch set 1.'}, {'timestamp': 1538680525, 'reviewer': {'name': 'redee', 'email': 'redee@mymail.com', 'username': 'redee'}, 'message': 'Patch Set 1:\n\ncatch_word: foo'}, {'timestamp': 1538680525, 'reviewer': {'name': 'redee', 'email': 'redee@mymail.com', 'username': 'redee'}, 'message': 'Patch Set 1:\n\ncatch_word: bar'}]}]
```

I need to get the words after last occurrence of `catch_word:` in the list, which is bar in this case.

I could convert it to dict:

```
>>> 
>>> dict=list[0]
```

Could print the comments too:

```
 >>> dict['comments']
[{'timestamp': 1536964726, 'reviewer': {'name': 'Sam', 'email': 'sams@mymail.com', 'username': 'sams'}, 'message': 'Uploaded patch set 1.'}, {'timestamp': 1538680525, 'reviewer': {'name': 'redee', 'email': 'redee@mymail.com', 'username': 'redee'}, 'message': 'Patch Set 1:\n\ncatch_word: foo'}, {'timestamp': 1538680525, 'reviewer': {'name': 'redee', 'email': 'redee@mymail.com', 'username': 'redee'}, 'message': 'Patch Set 1:\n\ncatch_word: bar'}]
```

Couldn't find how to get `bar`, note that it has more than one catch_word, e.g. `catch_word: foo`, but I am trying to get the last one, which is `bar`. if the last occurance has something like `'message': 'Patch Set 1:\n\ncatch_word: bar baz'`, then I need to get `bar baz` ,

same `bar baz` if it has `'message': 'Patch Set 1:\n\ncatch_word: bar baz\nblah blah blah'`

Comment: Define 'last'. Do you want it based off your timestamp value or just the last occurrence of the catch_word?

Comment: the last occurance of the catch_word, updated the post.

Comment: And you are wanting 'catch_word:bar' or just 'bar'?

Comment: just `bar`, actually everything after catch_word: till `\n` or till end (which is a single quote in this case)